# Master theorem application

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I am currently working on applications of the master theorem, where it came to pass that I failed to find a solution to a problem.

Given the recursion:

$T(n) = aT\left( \frac{n}{b} \right) + f(n)$

where $f(n)$ is a non-negative function of asymptotic growth $f(n) \in \theta \left( n^{\log_ba} \log n \right)$. Show that if $n = b^k, \, k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $T(n) \in \theta \left(n^{\log_b a} \log^2n\right)$.

(The $\log$ without any index is meant to be $\log_2$).

Now as far as I know, for such a recursive function the master theorem gives 3 possible cases:

1. if $\quad f(n) \in O\left( n^{\log_b a - \varepsilon} \right) \quad$ for a $\, \varepsilon > 0 \,$, then $\quad T(n) \in \theta \left(n^{\log_b a}\right)$
2. if $\quad f(n) \in \theta \left(n^{\log_b a}\right) \quad$ then $\quad T(n) \in \theta \left(n^{\log_b a} \log n\right)$
3. if $\quad \exists \, 0<c<1 \, \, \, \exists \, n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \, \, \, \, \forall n \geq n_0 : a f(\frac{n}{b}) \leq c f(n) \quad$ then $\quad f(n) \in \Omega \left( n^{\log_b a + \varepsilon}\right) \quad$ and $T(n) \in \theta\left( f(n) \right)$

I just can't see, how to usefully apply masters theorem here. I'd appreciate advice or hints.

Octavius

Comment: Actually, if $f(n)\in\Theta(n^{\log_b a}\log n)$ then $T(n)\in\Theta (n^{\log_b a}\log^2n)$ by my understanding of the master theorem (in the case where the work to split/recombine a problem is comparable to subproblems). The assumption that $n=b^k$ is just so that expressions of the form $T\left(\frac nb\right)$ are always evaluating $T$ with an integer argument.

Comment: This is what has to be prooven. Any ideas on how to get such a proof going?